# Hibernate the same column in the primary key and in the id

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have table with the multiple primary key so I have to create embeddable class. One column in this key is a foreign key to a different table. How to create JPA annotation for it?

```
public class ControlPlanLineEmbeddable implements Serializable{

    @Column(name = "[Control Plan No_]")
    String controlPlanNo;

    @Column(name ="[Version]")
    String version;

    @Column(name ="[Line No_]")
    int lineNo;   

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="Control Plan No_")
    ControlPlanSetup xxx;
....
```

So I have only 3 column and I'm trying to create 4 annotation. Column `Control Plan No_` is a part of the primary key and also foreign key in different table. I have to create `@ManyToOne` annotation, but I receive:

> A Foreign key refering POJO.ControlPlanSetup from POJO.ControlPlanLine
>   has the wrong number of column. should be 4

Comment: Could you share related tables schema?

Comment: Generally you can have both `@Id` and `@ManyToOne` annotations on a field, meaning that it is a primary key to this entity and at the same time a FK to the target. Also embeddable classes can contain relation fields. It would help if you added all the relevant parts of the code in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Last time I also needed to make my PK also FK of another entity. With help comes

> @MapsId

annotation from (javax.persistence.MapsId;). I'm sure that using it gonna solve Your issue.